# Save and restore xfce power management settings

Tags: ubuntu, restore, xfce, xubuntu, default-settings

Where are xfce power management settings saved?

Whenever I installed a new XUbuntu, I have to go through the same motion of tweaking each of xfce power management settings, e.g., when laptop lid is closed, I want it to suspend instead of do nothing. I.e., almost every single default setting I have to tweak. So,

I'm wondering if it save the settings to a file, then I just need to save that tweaked file, and no need to tweak each time after install a new XUbuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xfce stores its config in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/`. This files needs to be saved for backup. If you want to apply those settings, you can either copy the appropriate file in this directory while not logged in in xfce (because those files are not watched for changes and will be overwritten on a new save event) or you translate the settings into [xfconf-query](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query) commands which you can apply during xfce runtime.